# What is cache memory in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have some object,i stored in PostgreSQL table.Now I want to read particular object using cache.How I can apply there cache in my PostgreSQL Database.I saved some rule like-

(temp>25) && (motion == true);

In text format i saved this rule and i am using apache storm for        processing purpose because all time process is going to read rule from database for that i want to use in memory process in my database.

Comment: Please add more information about what you want to achieve? Run a Query, Function, etc? Which OS and PostgreSQL Version do you use?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 os and postgreSQL version is 9.3.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)